# Input dimension of MultiheadAttention varies between Pytorch and Tensorflow "Transformer Model for language understanding"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

In Pytorch's implementation of MultiheadAttention, TransformerEncoder, the Batch size is in the middle. That is (L,N,E) for query dimension.
But in Tensorflow's  "Transformer Model for language understanding" article, the query dimension is (batch_size,seq_len,depth). That batch_size is at 0th index.
Why this differs?

Comment: In Tensorflow `0th` position of input shape will be `batch_size`. I believe this  difference is because of the way these libraries has built. Thanks!